# Keep same height of an element in all resolutions

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have three elements, the ones in red are divs with images as background displaying the logo of my client. The white one is a "modal" window that appears when you click an item on the menu (not displayed), this modal window uses percentages for its height and uses a fixed position to stay in the center of the page (both vertically and horizontally). The bottom of the modal as to be aligned with the two red boxes.. For my resolution it works perfect, but when on a Macbook (for example) when on fullscreen the site looks like this

[image]

**What should I possibly do to solve this problem?**

In case someone needs it, here's the CSS of the modal

```
   .modal{
    cursor: auto;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 11;
    top: 45px;
    bottom: 15px;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 940px;
    max-width: 1072px;
    height: 81%;
    padding: 40px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    color: #1C1C1C;
    text-align: left;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
   }
```

Comment: Based on what you explain and show, the problem seems to be more on the side `<div>`s than on the _modal_ because is showed in the desired (horizontal and vertical) center. Could you please share a fiddle or the whole code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Remove the height property** in your modal, You must just stretch your modal by using `top` and `bottom`. This will make sure the bottom of the modal is 15px from the bottom of the screen.

> The bottom of the modal as to be aligned with the two red boxes..

Add the same Css rules to your red divs as well by using `top` and `bottom`

> this modal window uses percentages for its height and uses a fixed position to stay in the center of the page (both vertically and horizontally)

If you say that the modal will be centered even vertically then howw do you expect the side red divs to align correctly at the bottom?

For this you must use jquery and when ever the modal is `shown` calculate the number of pixels from the bottom of the window to the bottom of the modal and then add this pixels as the CSS rule to both the side div's bottom property. That way you will get it aligned

Comment: I can argue with the "you need to use JQuery for this" sentence.

Comment: @Bálint yes go ahead, I am open for it

Comment: Everything can be done in javascript, wich can be done in JQuery. Why would you go trough the trouble to download JQuery (if it isn't on your computer) and use that to do such a simple thing?

Comment: @Bálint Seeing his functionality of having a modal pop up and stuff I am damn sure he is already using Jquery :)

Comment: That's a good point. He could do it with CSS thoug, but I doubt it.

Comment: @Bálint Modal is having dynamic height in his scenario So CSS cannot act dynamically depending on another element.